# What is wrong with my SQL count query?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table with all my inventory ID and they all duplicated. So I'm looking at a table like this:

```
   ItemID   |   Price 
   1        |   5.50 
   1        |   5.50 
   2        |   6.50
   2        |   6.50
```

and so forth..

Now, when I run a query like this:

```
SELECT ItemID, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY ItemID
```

I get the following result:

```
   ItemID   |   count  
   1        |   1 
   1        |   1  
   2        |   1 
   2        |   1
```

Why is it giving me a count of 1 when its clearly 2?

**EDIT**: As most pointed out, it was due to an extra character in the ItemID. There was a linebreak one one of the duplicates. How it got there, I'm not sure. But thanks for the help.

Comment: which data type is the column ItemID ?

Comment: I cannot replicate this result

Comment: Is that the exact query, or have you "simplified it" by taking out something you didn't *think* was important?

Comment: It's obviously thinking the `ItemID` is different in each case, because it hasn't grouped them together (e.g. you have two rows returned with an `ItemID` of `1`)

Comment: This is your same code working as expected. Likely ItemID is a string with whitespace or something? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/03df5/1

Comment: Try `SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(ItemID)) AS id, COUNT(*) as count FROM Inventory GROUP BY LTRIM(RTRIM(ItemID))`

Comment: @scaisEdge the column ID is varchar

Comment: then you have hidden char in your itemID fields .. try remove with trim(itemID)

Comment: Ha, or you can make it unnecessarily longer like I did with `RTRIM(LTRIM(ItemID))` :P

Comment: @scaisEdge I did it the way doublesharp suggested with LTRIM(RTRIM(ItemID)) and I get the same results

Comment: There was a linebreak on the seemingly identical entries.

Comment: @abe  i have posted and answer .. try and et me know

Answer (score 0):

If `ItemId` always looks like a number, then you convert it to a number:

```
SELECT ItemID + 0, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY ItemID + 0;
```

However, the fundamental issue is that you would seem to have characters in `ItemId` that you do not expect.  These might be as simple as spaces at the end of the string, or they might be hidden characters of another sort.

Answer (score 0):

There are many method like add coloum_name+0 and trim(coloum_name) but you should
alter your table ItemID to int or update your table data with trim

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the hidden char using

```
SELECT trim(ItemID), COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY trim(ItemID)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT itemId,count(count) as have_this_many
FROM inventory
WHERE (SELECT DISTINCT(itemId) = itemId)
GROUP BY itemId
ORDER BY itemId

I am not sure what effect having a field name equal to an SQL function will have but I would name it to something like "on_hand".